# Gradle Eclipse not working correctly for subprojects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Gradle 2.4 and Eclipse Mars here. Here's my project directory structure:

```
myapp/  <-- root project
    myapp-client/
        src/main/groovy/*
        build.gradle <-- just declares some client-specific deps
    myapp-shared/
        src/main/groovy/*
        build.gradle <-- shared-specific deps
    myapp-server/
        src/main/groovy/*
        build.gradle <-- server-specific deps and how to package server JAR
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Where `myapp/build.gradle` is:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'codenarc'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    repositories {
        // ...etc.
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...etc.
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.4'
    }
}
```

And where `myapp/settings.gradle` is:

```
include ':myapp-shared'
include ':myapp-client'
include ':myapp-server'
```

When I do a `./gradlew eclipse` I get messages indicating that the command was successful. I then open Eclipse to import `myapp` as a series of individual subprojects.

#### Expectation based on what I'm used to seeing, historically

In previous projects that contained subprojects, I would go to `Import >> Existing Projects into Workspace`, where I would see this dialog:

[image]

I would then click `Browse` and select the project root (in this particular case, `myapp`). Eclipse would then auto-detect the 3 subprojects and populate them as a checked list inside the *Projects* component in the UI above. I would then click "*Finish*" and Eclipse would load the 3 subprojects into my workspace, each showing as a separate project (as it should).

#### What's actually happening

Instead, when I click on `myapp` as the root project, Eclipse just populates it as a single project, almost as if it doesn't detect that I have subprojects at all:

[image]

When I click *Finish* it imports a single project into my workspace, that has source folders for each of the 3 subprojects. And while that's just an annoyance, the real problem is that the classpath seems to be totally jacked up. For instance, I can add a class to `myapp-shared`, and then include it in a class defined inside `myapp-client`, and Eclipse doesn't force me to add an `import` statement into the client class! It's like the whole project is sharing the same package/namespace.

Can any Gradle gurus spot a defect in my Gradle setup that could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was nasty, but I figured it out. Posting the solution here in case anybody else runs into this.

---

1. Instead of a single `allprojects` closure, you need `allprojects` and `subprojects` closures. Not sure what is "safe" to put in either closure, but I got this working by simply declaring my `repositories` inside of `allprojects` and then putting everything else inside `subprojects`.
2. The problem was that I had previously ran `gradle eclipse` on the root project (before I added in the `subprojects` closure), and so Gradle generated the typical artifacts (e.g. `.projects`, `.classpath`, `.settings/*`) **in the parent/root project directory**. So...
3. Delete Gradle-Eclipse artifacts out of the root directory. Delete the project from your Eclipse workspace (**but not the disk!!!**). I'd even go so far as to restart Eclipse to clear out any caches if they exist.
4. Run `gradle clean` for good measure. Probably not needed.
5. Run `gradle eclipse` again.
6. Re-import into Eclipse, and all will be well in your kingdom once again, my friend.

Comment: Just to add one more step to this which happened in my case.


7. Go to Project Explore, click on parent project -> configure -> configure and detect nested project -> select your nested projects if not selected -> click on finish.

Now go to package explore you can see your nested projects.